# How to create an alphabetizer with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to create a very simple alphabetizer by asking the user to input text into a prompt box, which put into an array. Then, it'll alphabetize the words and output them. Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8" />
<title>Alphabetizier</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Meico's Alphabetizer</h1>
    <script>
    var input = [prompt("Enter your words here")];
    var alphabetize = input.sort();
    var string = alphabetize.join();
    console.log(string);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am temporarily using console.log and pressing F12 on my browser to see the result. I have no idea how to actually use HTML to output the alphabetized words.

Comment: @Sirko - Their real question is "how can I use JavaScript to output HTML instead of writing to the console?"

Comment: Also, get rid of the square brackets. They serve to make an array, in your case, with just a single item.

Comment: You can use ```document.write``` instead of ```console.log``` to see your output.

Comment: @Sirko: `.sort()` returns the original array. So `input === alphabetize; // true`

Comment: Don't use document.write. Learn about the DOM, and how to create elements in JavaScript. I'd start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Comment: What you're doing wrong is you're not converting the string of words into an Array of words. You need to decide what should delineate a word, and then `.split()` on that character or characters.

Comment: @elclanrs: With you here. @Meico Hsiao: To help you get started with the DOM: First add `<input type="text" id="words">` into your document, then learn how to read from that with JS instead of using `prompt`.

Comment: @MeicoHsiao If your issue has been fixed, then please accept an answer below, or submit your own answer with proper attributions and details

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your actual question is how to do DOM manipulation, which is... a bit of a question

I'll keep it simple, I suppose.

Add an element to your HTML to contain the words, first of all. Something like

```
<p id="words"></p>
```

To access that element through javascript, you will use

```
var words = document.getElementById("words");
```

There's an issue with your code, in that Array.sort() does not return a sorted array, but rather sorts in place. You should remedy this by removing the `alphabetize` variable, and just using `input`.

Now to actually add the text content to the paragraph, you should use the `Node.textContent` attribute like so:

```
words.textContent = input.join();
```

You can read up more on DOM manipulation on the mozilla devleper network here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Answer (score 1):

The `prompt` function simply returns a string - what the user inputted. So for example, if the user entered `hello, apple, green, chicken` into the prompt box, the array would contain 1 item, the string "hello, apple, green, chicken". If you want to split this string up by the delimiter ", ", then you can use the function `split` on the string. Your code would look like:

```
var input = prompt("Enter your words: ");
var words = input.split(", ");
words.sort();
console.log(words);
```

Another thing to note is that the `sort` function acts in place, meaning you don't assign a variable to it's result, because it doesn't return anything.

To output the words in HTML, you could use the function `document.getElementById` to get an `<ul>` (unordered list) object to which you could append the words:

```
var input = prompt("Enter your words: ");
var words = input.split(", ");
words.sort();

var list = document.getElementById("my-list");
for (var word in words) {
    var child = document.createElement("li");
    child.innerHTML = word;
    list.appendChild(child);
}
```

With this code your HTML would look like:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="my-list">
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea what you could do:

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/avvxuomb/)

## HTML

```
Input words: <input type="text" class="word">

<ul class="word-list"></ul>
```

## JS

```
var words = [];
// will render the contents of the list into the .word-list list
var showWords = function () {  
    words.sort();                              //sort the words
    var $list = $('.word-list');       
    $list.html('');                            // clear the last content of .word-list
    $.each(words, function () {                // iterate through the words
        $list.append('<li>' + this + '</li>'); // append a list item for each word (this refers to the word in the array
    });
};

$('.word').on('keyup', function (e) { // listen to each keypress in the input box
    if (e.which === 13) {             // if we pressed enter
        var $input = $(e.target);     // take the reference to the inputbox
        var word = $input.val();      // take the value of the input box 
        words.push(word);             // add it to the array
        $input.val('');               // clear the input box

        showWords();                  // show the words
    }        
});
```

This solution uses jQuery. I suggest you go through the used functions: [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [`.keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to be able to completely understand the code.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a `$` function, nor a `$` object with an `.each` method.

Comment: Answer was in the writing. just added the last section specifying the usage of jQuery